# Which came first, the shield or the sword?

Tags: weapons, sword

According to the history stated in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield#Prehistory_and_antiquity):

> The oldest form of shield was a protection device designed to block
>   attacks by hand weapons, such as swords, axes and maces, or ranged
>   weapon sling-stones and arrows.

Does this mean that the swords (or other weapons) came first before the shield? However, I am also thinking that shields were also made to block attacks from wild animals, for example, not just from hand weapons.

Is there historical evidence indicating which came first?

Comment: Hmm, this is probably so far back in pre-history that you would have to find hypotheses from archaeological evidence. For what its worth, chimpanzees will use will use sticks and stones as offensive weapons (source: my two Jane Goodall books) but do not use shields because they are incapable of making them.

Comment: @Mike Yes, I understand. I am also thinking that my question is somehow irrelevant.

Comment: A shield is necessary only to fend off against an attacking weapon. Logic would lead us to believe the attacking piece came first, which would only then necessitate the protection. Specifically WRT swords- well swords **may** have come after other attacking weapons, and therefore after shields.

Comment: @Rajib it's feasible that a device used for something else stated getting used as a shield against weapons. For exampl a safety helmet for a construction worker will also work against blunt weapons.

Comment: I seriously doubt this can be answered.

Comment: Somehow I suspect shield evolved with the blunt weapons and sharp poles. I will try to find evidence when I go home.

Comment: You could use a shield to scare off animals, and some people think homo sapiens were first scavengers before hunters. But you have to have a cutting instrument to make a shield, so the weapons absolutely came first. It could be the first use was to block attacks from animals while hunting though, not warfare. Most people think warfare didn't occur in most of the paleolithic period or it was very uncommon.

Comment: @jwenting - Swords and shields are objects we have a very good archaeological record for, and clear timelines of their development.

Comment: I vote to re-open in deference to @RISwampYankee, but I suspect the answer is co-evolution.

Answer (score 18):

The shield came first. The sword is an invention of the bronze age, but the shield has been used to protect against many types of weapons by stone age (*not primitive*) peoples. It is still in use today by traditional societies. For example: See pics of an [Australian aborigine](http://www.google.com/search?q=aboriginal%20warrior&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&imgil=cLTT2sMy_qKf_M%253A%253Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ft3.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcQydfivefMUjDuYRoazLR7Smuj9B5y7E47v8qSefowD6MRim2Lr%253B386%253B600%253BEz7doOtBnWq5tM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.antiqueprintroom.com%25252Fcatalogue%25252Fprint-print%25253Fid%2525253Dc6a94d2e1fbff73fd683c646fe6951f4%25252526catalogid%2525253D989cf604a6603f93e45e1a16f28182bb&source=iu&usg=__CrvHQj832nzLWuygvudxJ7qMYug=&sa=X&ei=xd47U4CjDNfMsQSsqIHgAw&ved=0CEQQ9QEwBQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=cLTT2sMy_qKf_M%253A;Ez7doOtBnWq5tM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.antiqueprintroom.com%252Fimage%253Fd508876ced1afd79061bd6ea69c4eb05;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.antiqueprintroom.com%252Fcatalogue%252Fprint-print%253Fid%253Dc6a94d2e1fbff73fd683c646fe6951f4%2526catalogid%253D989cf604a6603f93e45e1a16f28182bb;386;600) and a [Zulu warrior](http://www.google.com/search?q=zulu%20warrior&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&imgil=xcMWmBmNXz2U6M%253A%253Bhttp%253A%252F%25).

The shield is believe to have been invented in the late Neolithic Period. During the Neolithic, humans began invented more tools from wood, rather than only stone. An early shield would most likely be made from wood and humans would have co-invented it around the world at different times. Due to the fact that Australian Aborigines invented the shield, but not the bow, it is possible that it was invented around 10,000 BCE or before. The earliest cave drawings of organized warfare in Europe involve the use of formations and the bow, but not the shield. So, it is possible that the shield predates warfare, but it is unlikely. The Neolithic Period was a time when humans began animal husbandry and early agriculture. Soon population pressures led to warfare that is believed had not existed before this time. There was a huge increase in the manufacture of weapons, which can be seen in the archeological record. The invention of the shield is most likely a response to organized warfare and the invention of these weapons and was not used in earlier periods for another purpose, such as to a tool for protection while hunting. (Also when humans were hunter-gathers they would have had to carry the shield everywhere during their migrations.)

Comment: "The sword is an invention of the bronze age" Highly depends on your definition of sword. If it includes daggers, then it's most definitely a much earlier invention.

Comment: @YannisRizos though for a dagger you'd not use a shield as defense which is rather slow but vambraces which you can move to block with faster.

Comment: @YannisRizos "Historically, the sword developed in the Bronze Age, evolving from the dagger" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword

Comment: @YannisRizos - Axes and clubs were far more common infantry weapons in the chalcolithic and early bronze age. Daggers are fairly useless in combat, due to the reach and momentum of the larger weapons - it wasn't until bronzeworking became advanced enough to support flexible and strong blades that the dagger was lengthened to the sword - and even then, transitional weapons like the khopesh came first.

Comment: One clarification here: The Zulus were throughout their history an Iron Age people. They preferred fighting with spears to swords, but they were always iron-tipped.

Comment: @T.E.D. Do you have a source for the date of their iron adoption? I don't think it was before 1500-1600, near the time of Shaka, but they do have a cow based economy, which might make 1000 AD.

Comment: @RazieMah - Consider asking this as a question. Addressing it here would make for an over long (and quite off-topic) comment.

Comment: @T.E.D. Please note that the answer referred to the Zulu as a "traditional society," not a "stone age people."

Comment: @RazieMah - To be honest, that's my issue with your answer. Contemporary cultures that *seem* "primitive" are not good indicators of the technology used in pre-history. Artifacts and contemporary records (in depictions or written) are the only evidence of the existence of a certain technology at a certain time.

Comment: @RISwampYankee Inferences are drawn from modern tribes as well. That is the standard method. I was trying to look into TEDs comments, so here is a good book, very illustrative of how this works: http://books.google.com/books?id=dxWVmygHMPcC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=what+new+weapons+did+shaka+bring+to+the+zulu&source=bl&ots=HEuqz31Ozp&sig=Vc6LDvp1pJBbCC7E3xSB_ixK8Xo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Mak9U9O0NazLsQS504HYAg&ved=0CHEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=what%20new%20weapons%20did%20shaka%20bring%20to%20the%20zulu&f=false

Comment: @RazieMah - Sorry, I meant cultures contemporaneous to modern scholars. You cannot infer from modern-era (after 1492) Aboriginal culture when shields were introduced - you need reliably dated art depicting shields, written records of shields by contemporary writers, or reliably dated artifacts.

Comment: @RISwampYankee Yes I agree completely.

Answer (score 9):

The [Stele of the Vultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stele_of_the_Vultures) shows Sumerian spearmen employing shields - it's from the middle of the third millennium BCE. While long bronze daggers are found in parts of Anatolia about this time, true [bronze swords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_age_sword) longer than 60cm and strong enough to be used for weapon-to-weapon combat, would take another thousand years to become prevalent as metalworking improved.

[On the other hand](http://faculty.uml.edu/ethan_spanier/Teaching/documents/WarfareintheNeolithic.pdf) (pdf):

> Only one defensive weapon is known from the Neolithic, a wooden shield from a Late Neolithic
>   Globular Amphora tumulus in Langeneichstädt, Kr. Querfurt, Germany (Vencl 1999, 66).

So, while there is strong evidence for bows, daggers, axes and clubs being widespread among the warrior classes during the neolithic, defensive weapons like shields are notable by their absence. So, *weapons* probably preceded the shield in warfare.

Comment: Of course _weapons_ preceded the shield, he asked if _swords_ did.

Comment: He asked if "swords (or other weapons)" preceded the shield.